# NON-editable autoscrolling JTextArea

Tags: java

I have a JScrollPane with a JTextArea added to it. I then add the ScrollPane to the panel created for the gui. when running everything works as planned. The text that is typed into the input section is removed from input and added to the output. However when the text exceeds the size of the JTextArea it refuses to scroll after it. The code i will be providing is a lot as i do not know where the issue is or how to fix it.

I have browsed StackOverflow and have tried many different things i will give some links. How to set AUTO-SCROLLING of JTextArea in Java GUI? . as well as i have used the oracle website. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html . but none of them have helped me.

```
public Sork()
{
    txtara = new JTextArea("");
    panel = new JPanel();
    txtfld = new JTextField(""); 
    sb = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar = new JScrollPane(txtara, 
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    txtfld.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(740, 20));
    txtfld.setLocation(new Point (0, 510));
    txtfld.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    txtfld.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    txtara.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(740, 510));
    txtara.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    txtara.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    txtara.setEditable(false);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 575));
    panel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.add(scrollBar);
    panel.add(txtfld);

    txtfld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {               
            txtara.append("\n" + txtfld.getText());;
            txtfld.setText("");
            txtfld.grabFocus(); 
        }});
    }
```

I want the JTextArea to auto scroll once the text reaches the bottom. I should also mention i would like the actual scrollbar to not be visible, this is being made for a text based adventure. therefore the less showing the better.

Comment: Your code gives me the impression that you're a _Swing_ beginner. If that is true, I recommend first obtaining a good grounding in _Swing_ **before** embarking on a sophisticated project. I highly recommend the book _Core JFC 2nd Edition_ by Kim Topley. Very old but still very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. It uses hardly any of your code because I felt it would be more beneficial to you if I started from scratch. The code below displays a `JTextField` where you enter text. Below the `JTextField` is a (non-editable) `JTextArea`. Hitting the *Enter* key when keyboard focus is in the `JTextField` will append its text to the `JTextArea`. I recommend you make sure you thoroughly understand the code as I think it will push you along the *Swing* learning curve.

For your information the below code requires at least Java 7 since it uses *multi-catch*.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Sork implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea txtara;
    private JTextField txtfld;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actnEvnt) {
        Object src = actnEvnt.getSource();
        if (src == exitButton) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (src == txtfld) {
            txtara.append("\n");
            txtara.append(txtfld.getText());
            txtfld.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(exitButton);
        return panel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        txtara = new JTextArea(2, 10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtara);
        txtara.setLineWrap(true);
        txtara.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtara.setEditable(false);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createTextField() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        txtfld = new JTextField(10);
        txtfld.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(txtfld);
        return panel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Sork");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String slaf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(slaf);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException |
               InstantiationException |
               IllegalAccessException |
               UnsupportedLookAndFeelException x) {
            System.err.println("WARN (ignored): Failed to set [System] look-and-feel.");
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sork instance = new Sork();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are not seeing In my code snippet. Is that there is another class in which I have the frame and essentials crested. However you are not wrong, I am a swing beginner. Thank you for your help I will try this and see if it works.

Comment: can you help explain this to me please, what does @override do

Comment: Apparently you are also a java beginner. `@Override` is known as an [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). Annotations were introduced in Java 5. Perhaps you should spend some time going through the entire [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I am in a High School java class and my teacher has never mentioned annotations that is why i ask. aside from that I am not what would be called a newbie to java. but thank you for explaining.